# what type of url are both seo and user friendly?

Tags: seo, search-engine

What should be preferred url and why for seo and human out of

1. www for ex: www.discountbox.in or
2. non-www based url`s for ex: discountbox.in

On the similar lines do we need to have url`s like:
http://www.example.com/products/dresses/green

instead of:
http://www.example.com/products?category=dresses&color=green

to be more seo friendly?

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: is this forum not for seo????

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both of the examples above are user friendly, but http://www.example.com/products?category=dresses&color=green includes '=' and '?' characters which might seem confusing to the user.

Best Practices

- Use a directory structure that organizes your content well and makes it easy for visitors to know where they're at on your site.
- Try using your directory structure to indicate the type of content found at that URL.
- Remember that the URL is displayed as part of the search result[Google].
- **Google is good at crawling all types of URL structures, even if they're
  quite complex, but spending the time to make your URLs as simple as
  possible for both users and search engines can help**.

Avoid

- Having deep nesting of subdirectories like ".../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/page.html"
- Using directory names that have no relation to the content in them.

Source: [Google's SEO Guide](https://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEgQFjAB&url=http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf&ei=9mmDU-uOF9bAoASFgYGYDg&usg=AFQjCNEMj8KHxhxQz9cMLoMxMDiLdrAbJw&bvm=bv.67720277,d.cGU) pg. 8

Comment: Thanks. How about my first question about www & non-www urls. For some reason its not possible for me to have url without = and ?
Is this OK for seo or more friendly urls are better?

Comment: About www & non-www and from what I've researched, it's a debatable topic and find different opinions. Either way,the use of the  301 redirect is used to point one version of the site to the other(or vice versa). About the url with '=' or '?',this approach isn't bad for SEO.  I'd recommend to take a look at the SEO Guide stated in my answer, it's very short. The URL section it's 2-3 pages long.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly avoid query strings in your url. Use `.htaccess` file to rewrite query string to clean url.
Mostly use short urls and use `-` for empty spaces